# Convert Json string to object using Gson for dynamic class types

Tags: java, gson

I am trying to write a request router which would receive a HTTP POST request and based on the request's URL, convert the Json in the request's body to a corresponding Java class.

I have a Route class for encapsulating the routing url, handler, request and response class types. Below is a bare bones version of Route class without any getters and setters.

```
public class Route {
  public String url;
  public Class requestClass;
  public Class responseClass;

  public Route(String url, Class requestClass, Class responseClass) {
    this.url = url;
    this.requestClass = requestClass;
    this.responseClass = responseClass;
  }
}
```

I keep an ImmutableList for all the routes registered with the router.

```
ImmutableList.<Route>builder()
          .add(
              new Route(
                  "/getemployeebyfilters",
                  GetEmployeeByFiltersRequest.class,
                  GetEmployeeByFiltersResponse.class,
                  new GetEmployeeByFiltersHandler()))
          .add(
              new Route(
                  "/getcompanybyfilters",
                  GetCompanyByFiltersRequest.class,
                  GetCompanyByFiltersResponse.class,
                  new GetCompanyByFiltersHandler()))
          .build();
```

On receiving a new request, I read the Json body of the request and try to parse it into the corresponding class's object.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

Gson gson = new Gson();

for (Route route : routes) {
  if (route.url.equals(requestPath)) {
    GetEmployeeByFiltersRequest request = gson.fromJson(body, route.requestClass);
  }
}
```

This makes the compiler throw the following errors/warnings:

```
./Router.java:61: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method fromJson in class Gson is applied to given types
        GetEmployeeByFiltersRequest request = gson.fromJson(body, route.requestClass);
                                                           ^
  required: String,Class<T>
  found: String,Class
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>fromJson(String,Class<T>)
./Router.java:61: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        GetEmployeeByFiltersRequest request = gson.fromJson(body, route.requestClass);
                                                                       ^
  required: Class<T>
  found:    Class
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>fromJson(String,Class<T>)
./Router.java:61: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to GetEmployeeByFiltersRequest
        GetEmployeeByFiltersRequest request = gson.fromJson(body, route.requestClass);
                                                           ^
1 error
2 warnings
```

I would be really grateful if someone can point me in the right direction. I have the flexibility to change the Route class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can user com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper for convertion

Sample code

```
public static  <T> T convertJsonToObject(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz)  {
    T object = null;


        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        object = objectMapper.reader().forType(clazz).readValue(jsonString);

    return object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error which prevents a compiling Java project is due type-safety:

```java
./Router.java:61: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to GetEmployeeByFiltersRequest
        GetEmployeeByFiltersRequest request = gson.fromJson(body, route.requestClass);
```

The `fromJson` method is a [Generic Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) which means that it will return an object of the class type which is passed in as a parameter. However in this case the class type of `route.requestClass` is not known at **compile-time** (it could be of type `GetEmployeeByFiltersRequest` or of type `GetCompanyByFiltersRequest`).

In this case `gson.fromJson` can not guarantee that it will return an object of type `GetEmployeeByFiltersRequest`.  In fact `route.requestClass` could easily be of type `GetCompanyByFiltersRequest` which is a counter-example as to why Java won't compile this.

Changing the line to the following should compile however I would not recommend it as a design pattern:

```java
Object request = gson.fromJson(body, route.requestClass);
```

Now the request will be of a generic `Object` type and will lose all type safety.

I think a better alternative to handle request routing would be using some similar to the  [WebServlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation.

It allows you to specify a class which corresponds to an HTTP endpoint:

```java
@WebServlet("/employees")
class Employees extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
        // do stuff for employees 
    }
}

@WebServlet("/companies")
class Companies extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
        // do stuff for companies
    }
}
```